# How to customize a URL to use a name different than my Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, routes

I'm using ASP.NET MVC to develop a website and I need to customize my URL to use a name that is not the name of my Controller.

I want to use this Class/Method names:

```
public class CompanyController:Controller {
    public ActionResult About() {
        return View();
    }
}
```

But I want to use the URL **http://www.mysite.com/the-company/about-us** to access my Controller/Method.

How should I proceed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your question is mainly about controller naming I would (contrary to @Nissan Fan's answer) do at least this generalization, to make routing a bit more flexible and minimize the amount of routes, you'd have to define:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "CompanyRoute",
    "the-company/{action}",
    new { controller = "Company", action = "About" }
);
```

Your controller should of course be written this way:

```
public class CompanyController : Controller
{
    [ActionName("about-us")]
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View("About");
    }
}
```

Comment: While this is a reasonable alternative to hard routing the controller/action, having multiple routes is pretty efficient.  I'm not a fan of wildcard routing as it makes route debugging a mess.  You're essentially opening up any Action or public method on the CompanyController to access via your route add.

Comment: @Nissan Fan: Wise developers use action filters to avoid such security holes. I still tend to use generalized routes instead of having many single controller-action routes. You can always put `[NonAction]` attribute on controller methods that you don't want exposed (trat are not actions per se).

Comment: @Robert Not saying your approach is either incorrect or wrong, it's just a personal perference to use implicit routing when appropriate.  I think you're alternative solution shows a good feature which is ActionName aliases.  Either way the questioner is gaining from the input your provided and I upticked you accordingly.

Comment: At first, I would like to thank you both!
I have a little questions more about it: can I discard the 'new { controller = "Company", action = "About" }' parameter and just use the attributes [ActionName("")] on controller's method?

Comment: If you discard defaults, you will have problems, when someone will try to access: /the-company. **Which controller and which action should be executed?** That's why route defaults are for. They provide values when they're not provided within the request URL. Don't remove defaults.

Answer (score 2):

You will use URL Routing:

http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-05-cs.aspx

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "AboutUs",                                           // Route name
                "the-company/about-us",                            // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "CompanyController", action = "About" }  // Parameter defaults
            );
```